# SSRS datetimepicker and textboxes behave differently when using Weekday function

Tags: reporting-services, datetimepicker, weekday

In my SSRS report i have a date parameter and i want to set to it a default value with a complicated logic. I arrived at this strange behaviour:

Today is May 6th, wednesday. If i use the following expression:

```
DateAdd("d",Weekday(Today(),DayOfWeek.Sunday),Today())
```

for the default time picker I get May 9th.
If I use exactly the same expression in a textbox in the same report

```
DateAdd("d",Weekday(Today(),DayOfWeek.Sunday),Today()).ToLongDateString()
```

I get May 10th!
The only thing that changes is the toString.
Why are the two values different?
I tried with different expressions and the difference arises when i start using Weekday(Today(), somevalue)

Answer (score 0):

After a while and some fundamental help i realized that I had to use "FirstDayOfWeek" instead of "DayOfWeek" in both expressions for both of them to be the same regardless of current culture.